# Permissions for truncating a table

Tags: sql-server, database-permissions

What permission do I need to GRANT a user, in MSSQL, in order to be able to truncate a table?

I'm trying to grant the minimal set of permissions, but I can't use DELETE, because the table is very large, and I want the operation to be quick.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You need the ALTER permission: see the **Permissions** section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx).

Note that you can also use a stored procedure with EXECUTE AS, so that the user running the stored procedure does not need to even be granted the ALTER permission.

Comment: Not only was this answer correct, but did the "teach a man to fish" by pointing to the documentation so such answers can be found by the OP in the future.  Why the downvote?

Comment: @Ben - I suspect because the OP posted this answer about a nanosecond after posting the question. I didn't downvote though as the FAQ allows this.

Comment: @Martin - it wasn't a nanosecond. It was 2 minutes - that's how long it took me to find the answer.

Comment: tldr: grant alter on <table> to <user/role>

Comment: Granting ALTER permissions can be quite dangerous, so take care (read the CAUTION box): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-schema-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 9):

You can create a stored procedure `with execute as owner`:

```
create procedure dbo.TruncTable
with execute as owner
as
truncate table TheTable
go
```

Then grant execution permissions to whoever needs to truncate that table:

```
grant execute on TruncTable to TheUser
```

Now `TheUser` can truncate the table like:

```
exec dbo.TruncTable
```

Answer (score 8):

> The minimum permission required is
>   ALTER on table_name. TRUNCATE TABLE
>   permissions default to the table
>   owner, members of the sysadmin fixed
>   server role, and the db_owner and
>   db_ddladmin fixed database roles, and
>   are not transferable. However, you can
>   incorporate the TRUNCATE TABLE
>   statement within a module, such as a
>   stored procedure, and grant
>   appropriate permissions to the module
>   using the EXECUTE AS clause. For more
>   information, see Using EXECUTE AS to
>   Create Custom Permission Sets.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Don't GRANT, hide...

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_MyTable_Foo 
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
IF CONTEXT_INFO() = 0x9999
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable
    SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x00
END
GO

SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x9999
DELETE MyTable WHERE 1=0
```

SET CONTEXT_INFO <strike>may be</strike> is without any doubt **better** to separate a normal DELETE from a TRUNCATE TABLE

I haven't tried this...

**Edit**: changed to use SET CONTEXT_INFO.

Comment: +1 I would have said `SET CONTEXT_INFO` would be a must though to avoid causing unpleasant surprise!

Comment: -1 This would make a delete which hits zero rows truncate the table.  You're usually a great answerer, but this is an unmaintainable hack imho.

Comment: @Andomar: yes, corrected. I neither thought it through  fully nor updated my answer quickly enough

Answer (score -2):

You can create a stored procedure with execute as owner to only one table or a store procedure to any table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTruncate]
    @nameTable varchar(60)  
    WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
    AS

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(200);

SET @QUERY = N'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @nameTable + ';'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @QUERY;
```

Comment: @Graeme, why is this dangerous?  Both you and the other commenter think it is but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Hi, @FoxDeploy--
If some malicious user uses SQL Injection, such as this--
`DECLARE @nameTable VARCHAR(60) = 'SomeTable; DROP DATABASE YourDatabase; --';
EXECUTE dbo.spTruncate @nameTable;
GO`

More here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128412/sql-injection-is-17-years-old-why-is-it-still-around