# Entity Framework. Delete all rows in table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

How can I quickly remove all rows in the table using Entity Framework?

I am currently using:

```cs
var rows = from o in dataDb.Table
           select o;
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    dataDb.Table.Remove(row);
}
dataDb.SaveChanges();
```

However, it takes a long time to execute.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Reading the answers I wonder why none of these `TRUNCATE` adepts worry about foreign key constraints.

Comment: I'm kind of amazed by how the answers here just take for granted that everyone is using Microsoft SQL Server, even though support for other databases in Entity Framework goes back as far as I can find information about and certainly predates this question by several years. Tip: if an answer quotes table names in SQL statements with square brackets (like: `[TableName]`), it isn't portable.

Comment: Did id ever occur to you that "not using an ORM" is an answer? There is a lot of things ORM are made for - BULK OPERATIONS IS NOT ONE OF THEM. THere is no business logic involved in deleting all rows, and that is where ORM's shine.

Comment: check ef core 7: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#bulk-updates

Answer (score 378):

For those that are googling this and ended up here like me, this is how you currently do it in EF5 and EF6:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]");
```

Assuming context is a `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`

Edit:

Currently in net6.0 (dotnet 6 core) you can do the following:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]");
```

Or use the Async overload:

```
await context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]");
```

These are extension methods coming from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions`

If you're having issues with foreign keys (in MySql), you might have to do the following (Doing the `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` part in a separate call does not seem to work for me)

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName];");
```

So if you want to truncate your entire database (Possibly for unittesting reasons) - you can do the following:

```
var tableNames = context.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Select(t => t.GetTableName())
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

foreach (var tableName in tableNames)
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; TRUNCATE TABLE `{tableName}`;");
}
```

Comment: FYI, in order to use TRUNCATE the user must have ALTER permission on the table. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735038/permissions-for-truncating-a-table)

Comment: @Alex Just wasted a ton of time on the error "Cannot find the object MyTable because it does not exist or you do not have permissions." for that exact reason - ALTER permissions are rarely granted to EF apps, and the error message really sends you on a wild goose chase.

Comment: I had issues since my table was part of a foreign key relationship, even though it was the leaf table in that relationship.  I wound up using  
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM [Interests]"); instead

Comment: Note that while the `[` escapes here are specific to SQL Server, the `TRUNCATE` command is not - it's part of ANSI SQL and so will work in most SQL dialects (though not SQLite).

Answer (score 261):

***Warning:*** The following is only suitable for small tables (think < 1000 rows)

Here is a solution that uses entity framework (not SQL) to delete the rows, so it is not SQL Engine(R/DBM) specific.

This assumes that you're doing this for testing or some similar situation.
Either

- The amount of data is small *or*
- The performance doesn't matter

---

Simply call:

```
VotingContext.Votes.RemoveRange(VotingContext.Votes);
```

---

Assuming this context:

```
public class VotingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Vote> Votes{get;set;}
    public DbSet<Poll> Polls{get;set;}
    public DbSet<Voter> Voters{get;set;}
    public DbSet<Candidacy> Candidates{get;set;}
}
```

For tidier code you can declare the following extension method:

```
public static class EntityExtensions
{
    public static void Clear<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet) where T : class
    {
        dbSet.RemoveRange(dbSet);
    }
}
```

Then the above becomes:

```
VotingContext.Votes.Clear();
VotingContext.Voters.Clear();
VotingContext.Candidacy.Clear();
VotingContext.Polls.Clear();
await VotingTestContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I recently used this approach to clean up my test database for each testcase run (it´s obviously faster than recreating the DB from scratch each time, though I didn´t check the form of the delete commands that were generated).

---

**Why can it be slow?**

1. EF will get ALL the rows (VotingContext.Votes)
2. and then will use their IDs (not sure exactly how, doesn't matter), to delete them.

So if you're working with serious amount of data you'll kill the SQL server process (it will consume all the memory) and same thing for the IIS process since EF will cache all the data same way as SQL server. Don't use this one if your table contains serious amount of data.

Comment: Great answer, speeded up my delete all rows code by a factor of 10! Note that I had to rename the Clear() static extension method to something like ClearDbSet() since I already had another Clear() static extension method defined elsewhere in my project.

Comment: @dodgy_coder renaming isn´t necessary for reason you gave, since the extension method is for DbSet, IDbSet s and not IEnumerable, IList, ICollection, ICache or any other interface  that "Clear" would be required. the preference for extension method are the type on which the are defined. but if that reads clearer to you and doesn´t sound redundant, Great!.

i´,m glad it helps perfomance wise!

Cheers!

Comment: i'm glad you stated for small tables only. i hope people get the importance of your explanation. because this way is syntactic sugar, the proper way is the way Ron Sijm suggested. because you don't load the data before removing it. cheers though for showing and explaining this way of doing it.

Comment: This does not reset the identity key.  So if you clear 10 records, the next one will still be 11.

Comment: I had to explicity call `_context.SaveChanges()`explicitly after `RemoveRange`

Answer (score 109):

Update for EF Core 7+, we now have a [Bulk Deletion method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates) available as part of EF Core which means the specific method is implemented by the underlying provider (ie. not specific to SQL Server).

The problem with the original code as well as some other answers is that you're loading all of the entities in the table in to memory to be able to delete them. EF Core 7 shipped with a workaround for this.

You can now do:

```cs
await context.Table.ExecuteDeleteAsync();
```

For SQL implementations this will map to a `DELETE FROM` query being generated. There is no support for this in the NoSQL (Cosmos DB) provider as far as I can see.

Note that you still have to consider relationship deletions (you can simply use the same call on any related tables), as well as the loss of `TRUNCATE TABLE` and no longer resetting any Identity properties. You can however reset this yourself (SQL Server):

```sql
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[Table]', RESEED, 0);
```

---

Original:

Using SQL's [`TRUNCATE TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177570.aspx) command will be the fastest as it operates on the table and not on individual rows.

```
dataDb.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Table]");
```

Assuming `dataDb` is a `DbContext` (not an `ObjectContext`), you can wrap it and use the method like this:

```
var objCtx = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)dataDb).ObjectContext;
objCtx.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Table]");
```

Comment: If you get a permissions error when you try this, just change `TRUNCATE TABLE` to `DELETE FROM`

Comment: @codeMonkey just take note that these are different operations, but will have (almost) the same net effect 

Comment: But DELETE doesn't reset the IDENTITY seed. This could be problematic in certain situations.

Answer (score 50):

```
var all = from c in dataDb.Table select c;
dataDb.Table.RemoveRange(all);
dataDb.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This should not be used cause you execute a full select and a delete after instead of just a delete. From time-performance view this is a big NOT!

Comment: @HellBaby Unless it's a rarely called and thus the performance is quite irrelevant.

Comment: Even if its rarely called this is bad. A table with merely 3000 entries could take upwards of 30 seconds due to how slow EF change tracking is.

Comment: This is only suitable for small tables ( < 1000 rows)

Comment: Perfect for my In-memory Database in my Unit Tests :)

Comment: be carefull, if you have autogenerated columns with values that matters.  deleting this way won't reset the identity seed.  Truncate does.

Answer (score 40):

```
using (var context = new DataDb())
{
     var ctx = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
     ctx.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM [TableName] WHERE Name= {0}", Name);
}
```

or

```
using (var context = new DataDb())
{
     context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]");
}
```

Comment: but when i write it."query.Delete();" - "Delete" does not recognized

Comment: add reference of System.Data.Entity and EntityFrameWork in ur current project

Comment: What extension method is Delete?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't an extension method `Delete` on `IQueryable` -- I'm guessing Manish was using something like EntityFramework.Extended: https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

Comment: I've edited my answer, earlier it was misleading. @null, you are right, this `.Delete` was a custom extension and in the heat of posting the answer first, totally forgot to mention the definition of this custom `.Delete`. :)

Comment: ExecuteSqlCommand is obsolete, instead use ExecuteSqlRaw

Answer (score 35):

You can do that without Foreach

```
dataDB.Table.RemoveRange(dataDB.Table);
dataDB.SaveChanges();
```

This will remove all rows

Comment: Will it truncate navigation property items?

Comment: only for small tables

Answer (score 25):

[EF Core 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates) solves this problem once and for all by adding bulk update and delete semantics:

```
await dataDB.Table.ExecuteDeleteAsync();
```

Note that this syntax *immediately* executes the underlying (SQL) command to delete the data from the table. It does not fiddle around with tracking the entity, marking it for deletion, and waiting for `UpdateDatabase` to execute the transaction against the database.

Also note that multiple `ExecuteDelete` and `ExecuteUpdate` commands will not be contained in a single transaction by default. However, the DbContext transaction APIs can be used in the normal way to wrap these commands in a transaction.

Comment: This should be the preferred answer for this question, custom SQL will *not* work across different database engines.

Answer (score 22):

This avoids using any sql

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var itemsToDelete = context.Set<MyTable>();
    context.MyTables.RemoveRange(itemsToDelete);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I voted up for the simplicity (for small tables) but avoid using dispose with entity framework: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15667073/3231884

Answer (score 15):

```
context.TableName.RemoveRange(context.TableName);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @mahen3d Which link?

Answer (score 10):

I came across this question when I had to deal with a particular case: fully updating of content in a "leaf" table (no FKs pointing to it). This involved removing all rows and putting new rows information and it should be done transactionally (I do not want to end up with an empty table, if inserts fails for whatever reason).

I have tried the `public static void Clear<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet)` approach, but new rows are not inserted. Another disadvante is that the whole process is slow, as rows are deleted one by one.

So, I have switched to `TRUNCATE` approach, since it is much faster and it is also [ROLLBACKable](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/03/04/sql-server-rollback-truncate-command-in-transaction/). It also resets the identity.

Example using repository pattern:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private readonly IEfDbContext _context;

    public void BulkInsert(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        _context.BulkInsert(entities);
    }

    public void Truncate()
    {
        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"TRUNCATE TABLE {typeof(T).Name}");
    }
 }

 // usage 
 DataAccess.TheRepository.Truncate();
 var toAddBulk = new List<EnvironmentXImportingSystem>();

 // fill toAddBulk from source system
 // ...

 DataAccess.TheRepository.BulkInsert(toAddBulk);
 DataAccess.SaveChanges();
```

Of course, as already mentioned, this solution cannot be used by tables referenced by foreign keys (TRUNCATE fails).

Comment: Two comments: 1. The table name should be wrapped in [...]. One of my classes/tables is called "Transaction", which is a SQL keyword. 2. If the goal is to clear all tables in a DB for unit testing, issues with foreign key constraints can easily be worked around by ordering the tables to process them in a way that child tables get truncated before parent tables.

Comment: @Christoph - 1. Yes, that is true. I missed that, because I always name tables to avoid keywords as it might lead to trouble. 2. If I remember correctly, tables referenced by FKs cannot be truncate (SQL Server throws `Cannot truncate table because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint`), even if they are empty, so FKs must be [dropped and recreated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/cannot-truncate-table-because-it-is-being-referenced-by-a-foreign-key-constraint) in order to use `TRUNCATE` anyway.

Answer (score 7):

If

```
using(var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(@"TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable"););
}
```

causes

> Cannot truncate table 'MyTable' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

I use this:

```
using(var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(@"DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID != -1");
}
```

Comment: If you have foreign key constrains: (1) SQL could be simplified to "DELETE FROM MyTable".  (2) This will not reset the Id counter if you have it set to autoincrement (truncate does).

Answer (score 5):

```
var data = (from n in db.users select n);
db.users.RemoveRange(data);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 5):

The following works on SQLite database (using Entity Framework).

It seems that the fastest way to clear all the db tables is using `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("some SQL")`, as some comments above highlighted as well. Here I am going to show how to reset the 'index' count of tables too.

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from TableA");
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from sqlite_sequence where name='TableA'");//resets the autoindex

context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from TableB");
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from sqlite_sequence where name='TableB'");//resets the autoindex 

context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from TableC");
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from sqlite_sequence where name='TableC'");//resets the autoindex
```

One important point is that if you use foreign keys in your tables, you must first delete the child table before the parent table, so the sequence (hierarchy) of tables during deletion is important, otherwise a SQLite exception may occur.

Note: `var context = new YourContext()`

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to clear your entire database.

Because of the foreign-key constraints it matters which sequence the tables are truncated. This is a way to bruteforce this sequence.

```
    public static void ClearDatabase<T>() where T : DbContext, new()
    {
        using (var context = new T())
        {
            var tableNames = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%Migration%'").ToList();
            foreach (var tableName in tableNames)
            {
                foreach (var t in tableNames)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        if (context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format("TRUNCATE TABLE [{0}]", tableName)) == 1)
                            break;

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
ClearDatabase<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

remember to reinstantiate your DbContext after this.

Answer (score 2):

In EFCore (version i am using is 3.1) you can use the following to remove all rows -

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]");
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me... EF v3.1.5

```
context.ModelName.RemoveRange(context.ModelName.ToList());
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: worked for me also .. Entity Framework Core (dotnet 6)

Answer (score 2):

It is a very clean solution.

```
_context.RemoveRange(_context.ModelName);

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works Properly in EF 5:

```
YourEntityModel myEntities = new YourEntityModel();

var objCtx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)myEntities).ObjectContext;
objCtx.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all records. Do not reset the primary index like "truncate".

```
/// <summary>
/// SET - DELETE all record by table - no truncate - return deleted records
/// </summary>
public static int setListDelAllMYTABLE()
{
    // INIT
    int retObj = 0;
    using (MYDBEntities ctx = new MYDBEntities())
    {
        // GET - all record
        var tempAllRecord = ctx.MYTABLE.ToList();
        // RESET
        ctx.MYTABLE.RemoveRange(tempAllRecord);
        // SET - final save
        retObj += ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
    // RET
    return retObj;
}
```

Comment: why would you pull out all the records to delete them? extremely inefficient

Comment: Because performance was not my priority. It's based on modularity, so if you want to add a where condition or check the data before removing it, you can. EF6 is the slowest tool about SQL I/O, so why using EF6 if performance was the priority should be the question..

Answer (score 0):

If MVC, you can do:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAll()
{
    var list = await _context.YourClass.ToListAsync();
    _context.YourClass.RemoveRange(list);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you are trying to delete parent all children will cascade on delete. Or children have nullable foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation on the popular [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18986676/529618) by Ron that avoids the use of hardcoded string table names by taking advantage of another popular solution on stack overflow for determining the underlying table name for an entity framework class.

With these extension methods the solution looks like this:

```cs
_dbContext.TruncateTable<TheTableName>();
```

*(use `this.TruncateTable<...` if you're editing code within an EF DBContext class or partial class file)*

And here's the extension class:

```cs
public static class EntityFrameworkExtensions
{
    private static string ParseTableNameFromSQL(string sql)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("FROM (?<table>.*) AS");
        Match match = regex.Match(sql);

        string table = match.Groups["table"].Value;
        return table;
    }
    
    public static string GetTableName<T>(this IObjectContextAdapter context) where T : class =>
        ParseTableNameFromSQL(context.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().ToTraceString());
    
    public static void TruncateTable<T>(this DbContext dbContext) where T : class =>
        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"TRUNCATE TABLE {dbContext.GetTableName<T>()}");

    public static void DeleteAllTableRows<T>(this DbContext dbContext) where T : class =>
        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"DELETE FROM {dbContext.GetTableName<T>()}");
}
```

The last extension method `DeleteAllTableRows` is a useful alternative if your table cannot be truncated (e.g. due to foreign key references) - this is still much faster than the Entity Framework `RemoveAll` alternative.

Comment: Yet another truncate table answer :(. Hardly ever can a table be truncated.

Comment: @GertArnold just for you, I added a `DELETE FROM` extension as well (which indeed, I often have to fall back on in a number of scenarios)

Comment: This appears to be using the `DbContext` from `System.Data.Entity` instead of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`. You say this is based on a "popular solution on Stack Overflow"; do you have a link to this popular solution?

Answer (score 0):

Works for EF Core 3

```
public static class EntityExtensions
{
    public static async Task ClearAsync<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet) where T : class
    {
        var command = dbSet.CreateDbCommand();
        command.CommandText = $"TRUNCATE TABLE {dbSet.EntityType.GetSchema()}.{dbSet.EntityType.GetTableName()}";
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

but please note that dbSet.CreateDbCommand is an extension

Comment: Nice! However, why wouldn't ya supply the extension then!

Answer (score 0):

My solution, mixing my ideas, some answers ([Ron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18986676/2617826) one from this thread, but also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17712575/2617826) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6624689/2617826) for reflection) and trying to cover some different conditions.

It is based on EF6, but it should work fine, just fixing some extensions like `GetTableName<TEntity>`.

My solution:

- uses extensions, so you only need `DbSet` to launch
- has a row count threshold, to decide between `RemoveRange` or SQL execution, to avoid perfomance issues
- the SQL version is based on `DELETE` instead of `TRUNCATE`, to avoid foreign key issues (it has to fit your requirements, of course)
- has a parameter to save changes inline

```cs
private const int RangeLimit = 100;

private static void ClearTable<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dataSet, bool saveChanges = true) where TEntity : class
{
    DbContext context = null;

    if (dataSet.Count() > RangeLimit)
    {
        context = dataSet.GetContext();
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"DELETE FROM [{context.GetTableName<TEntity>()}]");
    }
    else
    {
        dataSet.RemoveRange(dataSet);
    }

    if (!saveChanges)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (context == null)
    {
        context = dataSet.GetContext();
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}

private static DbContext GetContext<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet)
    where TEntity : class
{
    var internalSet = dbSet
        .GetType()
        .GetField("_internalSet", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        ?.GetValue(dbSet);
    var internalContext = internalSet?.GetType().BaseType
        ?.GetField("_internalContext", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        ?.GetValue(internalSet);
    return (DbContext)internalContext?.GetType()
        .GetProperty("Owner", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        ?.GetValue(internalContext, null);
}

public static string GetTableName<TEntity>(this DbContext context) where TEntity : class
{
    return (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().EntitySet.Name;
}
```

All you have to do, with a database table named `Entries`, is:

```cs
databaseContext.Entries.ClearTable();
```

if you want to save changes, or if you don't want:

```cs
databaseContext.Entries.ClearTable(false);
```

It is based on reflection, to simplify code. It has some performance tradeoff, of course, but reflection happens once for each table, hence should be completely acceptable in these conditions.

Answer (score -2):

There are several issues with pretty much all the answers here:

1] Hard-coded sql. Will brackets work on all database engines?
2] Entity framework `Remove` and `RemoveRange` calls. This loads all entities into memory affected by the operation. Yikes.
3] Truncate table. Breaks with foreign key references and may not work accross all database engines.

Use https://entityframework-plus.net/, they handle the cross database platform stuff, translate the delete into the correct sql statement and don't load entities into memory, and the library is free and open source.

*Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with the nuget package. They do offer a paid version that does even more stuff.*

Comment: Using a third-party library (when not absolutely necessary) is also an issue. They change, they get deprecated, they turn into paid libraries, etc. I'd rather use SQL.

Comment: Sure. You can always take a snapshot of the 3rd party library and integrate it as is, no chance of breakage if you do it that way.

Comment: But even if you reference the nuget package directly that’s why one writes integration tests ;) but to each their own.