# Delete a big list of items with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-delete

I want to delete a big list of items with EF, so I tried to remove them one by one but it take long time.

And I tried to use `.RemoveAll()` method with my list but it don't update the database [only remove from loaded entity]

So I use a `SqlCommand` to remove them from the database and I use `.RemoveAll()` to prevent EF `unexpected number of rows update (0)` exception.

Code:

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM xxx WHERE xxx");
loadedEntity.subItems.ToList().RemoveAll(r => true);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

My question: is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220411/entity-framework-delete-all-rows-in-table

Comment: I update the question, I don't want to delete all Items in table I just want to delete all sub Items. IE: delete all products inside market.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try this

```
var all = dbContext.XXX.Where(x => x.xxx == "xxx");
dbContext.XXX.RemoveRange(all);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I don't have this method .RemoveRange() in my dbContect

Comment: @user1150331 update your ef to 6.0 and you will get .

Comment: Note - this is still a good response for EF/.Net Core, circa 2020.

Comment: Still works great 23'!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [batch extensions](http://mvcdiary.com/2012/02/08/entityframework-4-1-extensions-for-batch-delete-and-update/). ([one](http://efe.codeplex.com/) or [two](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended))

Deletion will be as simply as `dbContext.XXX.Delete(x => x.xxx == "xxx")`.

Answer (score 0):

**Entity Framework Core**

> 3.1 3.0 2.2 2.1 2.0 1.1 1.0

```
using (YourContext db = new YourContext())
{
    var foundList=db.YourDbSet.Where(c=>c.YourProp=='someVal').ToList();
    db.YourDbSet.RemoveRange(foundList);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Summary**:

> Removes the given collection of entities from the context underlying the set
>       with each entity being put into the Deleted state such that it will be deleted
>       from the database when SaveChanges is called.

**Remarks**:

> Note that if System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextConfiguration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled
>       is set to true (which is the default), then DetectChanges will be called once
>       before delete any entities and will not be called again. This means that in some
>       situations RemoveRange may perform significantly better than calling Remove multiple
>       times would do. Note that if any entity exists in the context in the Added state,
>       then this method will cause it to be detached from the context. This is because
>       an Added entity is assumed not to exist in the database such that trying to delete
>       it does not make sense.

Comment: You're correct.  But... 1) that's basically what user4093832 already said [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26905494/421195) (six years ago), and 2) More often than not you'll probably already have a dbContext - there's seldom a need for "using/new Context()" in most "real world" code.

Comment: Sorry for making you confusing. 1. I learned it from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removerange?view=netcore-3.1). 2. It is really for the OP 's example. Thank you.