# Emptying tables with Entity Framework with FK Constraints

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, localdb

I have looked around and found ways of clearing a table using TRUNCATE, this however only works with tables that are not being referenced as a foreign key.

I have also found a method which describes finding the range of all the data, and then deleting that range. This is however a somewhat less efficient way, and would like to avoid it if there is a better alternative.

What would be the most efficient way to empty these 2 tables?

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public String ProductNaam { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Afdeling")]
    public int? AfdelingID { get; set; }
    public virtual Afdeling Afdeling { get; set; }
}

public class Afdeling
{
    public int AfdelingId { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate in a .net 4.5 WPF project, with Entity Framework 6.1.2 and LocalDB

Comment: Should you program do this (clear tables)? Or what?

Comment: Does anything else rely on the on `AfdelingId` or `ProductId`?

Comment: I want it to be in my C# code, but it may use direct SQL if that works better. There is another FK to Product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of : [Entity Framework. Delete all rows in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220411/entity-framework-delete-all-rows-in-table)

Check the community wiki answer.

```
public static void Clear<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet) where T : class
{
    dbSet.RemoveRange(dbSet);
}
```

Then

```
DbContext.Afedlings.Clear();
DbContext.Products.Clear();
await VotingTestContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Of course assuming that you can keep track of relationships. Cheers.