# Reset table in SQL MVC Code First

Tags: sql, sql-server, model-view-controller, datatable, entity-framework-migrations

I have a MS SQL database that contains multiple tables. 
Recently, a new table was added for another feature on the application.
I found myself in an infinite loop storing all of the data in this table.
I do not want to delete the data from the other tables, so how do I quickly just reset this specific table.

**edit**

So, if you have your Server Explorer on the left hand side of Visual Studio. (Can launch using Ctrl+Q and searching). Right Click "New Query" and type as Ben Fried said.

Comment: Several options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220411/entity-framework-delete-all-rows-in-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `TRUNCATE` the table you want to "reset."  For example:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE mytable
```

For MS SQL, more info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx

For MySQL, more info here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: SQL database, and do I run that in SQL Manager?  Or is there a way to do that from Visual Studio?

Comment: You would run that command as an SQL query in SQL Manager, correct.

Comment: I also added a link to my answer for MS SQL that gives you all the info on the TRUNCATE command.