# How can I efficiently delete all records in a table using Entity Framework without using SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to remove all records in a given table, using a DbContext in Entity Framework. I need this to be portable, so it can't rely on SQL statements or stored procedures. I've looked through the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220411/entity-framework-delete-all-rows-in-table), but none of them meet my requirements or are ideal solutions for a variety of reasons.

I could use the RemoveRange method, i.e.

```
DbContext.Table.RemoveRange(all);
```

But this doesn't scale well, because it selects all entries before deleting, which could take a long, long time with Entity Framework. Iterating through each record and removing them individually with Remove(record) has the same problem.

Using SQL this is simple, using a TRUNCATE command. Even a simple DELETE FROM [TableName] command works, but I don't know how scalable that is.

Is there any solution that uses only Entity Framework (no SQL), and doesn't require selecting all records first before deleting them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220411/entity-framework-delete-all-rows-in-table

Comment: "so it can't rely on SQL statements " - TRUNCATE TABLE seems safe enough

Comment: @MitchWheat TRUNCATE TABLE is an SQL statement. And you'll also note that I linked to that question you've linked to, and read the answers there.

As [those answers point out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220411/entity-framework-delete-all-rows-in-table#comment84222294_15220411), "if an answer quotes table names in SQL statements with square brackets (like: [TableName]), it isn't portable."

Comment: I know it's a SQL Statement! lol   I'm saying show me a a RDBMS that doesn't support TRUNCATE TABLE tablename;

Comment: You need to extend the DbContext to provide more efficient method of Bulk deleting, there's no built in alternative that will work for you.
There's also a commercial option: https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-delete, where it takes 75ms to do BulkDelete vs 6s from SaveChanges.
You can obviously write it yourself as an extension.

Comment: @Tomasz Can you suggest a way of writing such a DbContext extension? I don't know how the commercial option you've linked does it, but I don't want to spend $80+ to find out it just uses an SQL statement behind the scenes.

Comment: @MitchWheat if you read through the answers to the question both you and I have linked, you'll see that there are a number of issues with using a TRUNCATE command that others have pointed out. Not least of which is it bypasses Entity Framework to execute raw SQL, undermining the whole point of using Entity Framework.

Comment: 'horses for courses' - I don't subscribe to the notion that you have to do things only one way.

Comment: @MitchWheat There are also, as noted in those answers, other problems with using a TRUNCATE command, including: it requires ALTER permissions not typically available to an EF app; it runs into errors with foreign key constraints.

It's not just a matter of choosing to exclusively use EF, it's also about trying to avoid those and other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not something that is possible using Entity Framework. see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/795

There may be an extension out there that will allow you to do that, but I am not sure it will work will all RDBMS systems.

Comment: Wow, that GitHub thread is a horror show. Six years, and a feature useful for almost all database-based applications is "likely to be a high-priority feature" for the release after next...

It does sound like I'll have to look at a third-part extension and see what works scalably for my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have BrandData table with records about some brands:

```
public class BrandData
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Also you've created a dbcontext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.Migrate();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<BrandData>().HasData(new BrandData { Id = 999, Name = "LG", Description = "TV brand" });
            
        }
        public DbSet<BrandData> BrandData { get; set; }

    }
```

Finally, this is the method that deletes brand by its ID:

```
public async Task DeleteModelAsync(int id)
        {
            var data = _dbContext.ModelData.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == id);
            if (data != null)
            {
                _dbContext.ModelData.Remove(data);
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
```

Changes will be done after SaveChangesAsync() method run.

**UPDATE**

To delete all records:

```
    var brands = await _dbContext.BrandData.ToListAsync();
    
                    foreach(var brand in brands)
                    {
                        _dbContext.BrandData.Remove(brand);
                    }

    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: This does not delete ALL rows in a table

Answer (score 0):

This thread merits a working answer. This is how you can do (EF 6)

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var subs = context.Subscriptions
        .Where(x => x.Client == myClient)
        .ToList();

    context.Subscriptions.RemoveRange(subs);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```