# Issue with truncating table WITH ALTER permissions

Tags: sql, oracle, truncate

I have read here [Permissions for truncating a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735038/permissions-for-truncating-a-table) that you need to grant ALTER permissions to the user(s) for them to be able to truncate a table. However, I am still having issues truncating the table with the user(s) being granted this role.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas why this is?

PS. I myself as the owner of the table am able to truncate by the way. Just no one else with ALTER permissions.

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52828/what-permissions-are-necessary-for-truncating-a-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you are referring to is applicable to MS SQL Server. The link in the comment by Leila is also for SQL Server.

For Oracle the users [must have](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10007.htm#SQLRF01707) the `DROP ANY TABLE` system privilege.

This in turn may not be what you want, as this system privilege is too destructive.

Tom Kyte [has](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1458414958491) a solution for your problem:

> Sure, this is what stored procedures are all about.
>
> To selectively give someone the abilitly to truncate a specific table,
>   or all of the tables owned by some schema, you would code:
>
> ```
> create or replace procedure do_the_truncate as begin execute immediate
> 'truncate table T'; end;
> ```
>
> or (any of the tables owned by some schema, or if that schema has the
>   drop any table priv ANY table)
>
> ```
> create or replace procedure do_the_truncate( p_tname in varchar2 ) as
> begin execute immediate 'truncate table ' || p_tname; end;
> ```
>
> and then just grant execute on that procedure to any user that needs
>   to run that command. Since stored procedures run with the base privs
>   of the OWNER of the procedure, you do not need any powerful privs like
>   "drop any table" to truncate that table.

You can further enhance the `do_the_truncate` stored procedure to have a list of allowed tables to be truncated to tighten the security in your system